# Meaning of self keyword in ruby

Tags: ruby

Is the keyword self in ruby is some thing like this keyword in java. If yes, could any one help me to grab the concept of it. Is it calling the current object? What's the point of calling an object?

Comment: the java equivalent is "this" as it is in many other languages

Comment: `self` refers to the current context which is always an object but might be a class or instance depending on where the code is defined.